# MongoDB sort overflow with PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pymongo

I have collection "doc" containing a field called "topic". It is initialized to -1 and when I get the topic, I update the field with the corresponding topic e.g. sports. When I do a query in **PyMongo** `db["doc"].find({"topic": -1}).sort("time",pymongo.DESCENDING).batch_size(batch_size)`
I get

> database error: getMore executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554846 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes

However, When I run this query on mongo shell:
`db.doc.find({"topic":-1}).sort({"time":-1}).batchSize(10000)`, It works without any problem. I have  single indices-{time:-1},{topic:1} and compound index-{topic:1,time:-1} (Compound index). Is there are any reason for this behavior?

Comment: db["doc"].find({"topic": -1}).sort("time",pymongo.DESCENDING).batch_size(batch_size) what's the batch_size here ?

Comment: it's weird. Can you try to just select 10 and be sure you got result time descending.